# How do I use input type <button> to launch a fancybox gallery?

Tags: jquery, fancybox-2

I am trying to use [fancybox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) to show a series of inline html elements (gallery).

Here is my button that fires fancybox:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary fancybox" data-fancybox href="myGallery">Example</button>
```

Here is the markup that contains the slide(s).

```
<section id="myGallery">
    <article rel="gallery1">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <p>Slide One</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
   </article>
   <article rel="gallery1">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <p>Slide Two</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
   </article>
</section>
```

Here is the javascript I'm using to listen for the button click(s).

```
$('.fancybox').click(function (event) {
    $.fancybox({
         'type': 'inline',
         'openEffect': 'fade',
         'closeEffect': 'fade',
         'maxWidth': 500,
         'maxHeight': 400,
         'padding': 80
    });
});
```

It's "working", but as you can guess I get the 
`The requested content cannot be loaded. Please try again later.` error message.

**EDIT**

Well, I've managed the window to load the content, but still struggling to get a gallery to work.

**html**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary fancybox" 
                      rel="gallery1"
                      data-fancybox-href="#myGallery">
    Example
</button>

<div id="myGallery">
    <article rel="gallery1">One</article>
    <article rel="gallery1">Two</article>
</div>
```

**js**

```
 $('.fancybox').fancybox({
     'type': 'inline',
     'openEffect': 'fade',
     'closeEffect': 'fade',
     'maxWidth': 500,
     'maxHeight': 400,
     'padding': 80
});
```

Comment: I guess you copy the demo of the web page right? So if you modified it, try to check all items are in the correct paths, like images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

Here is my solution in case someone comes across this with the same trouble.

**html**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary fancybox" data-fancybox-href="#myGallery">
    Example
</button>

<section id="myGallery">
    <article class="inlinedata">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="col-xs-12">Slide One</div>
        </div>
    </article>
    <article class="inlinedata">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="col-xs-12">Slide Two</div>
        </div>
    </article>
    ...
</section>
```

**js**

```
$('.fancybox').click(function (event) {
    $.fancybox.open($('.inlinedata').get(), {
        'type': 'inline',
         'openEffect': 'fade',
         'closeEffect': 'fade',
         'showNavArrows': true,
    });
});
```

**css**

```
.inlinedata {
    display: none;
}
```

Obviously, the actual settings in your fancybox config will vary. Hope this helps!